# How to load entity with its 1 to 1 relation in DataNucleus, using native SQL query with JOINS

Tags: datanucleus

I have an entity

```
class LoanApplication{
    private Account account;
    //...
}

class Account{
    private LoanApplication loanApplication;
}
```

I want to use the following native query

```
select * from account a left join loan_application la on a.id = la.account_id where a.id in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

And get a Set of Account objects with LoanApplication objects.
How to do it with DataNucleus?

Comment: makes no sense to do it in SQL and throw away database independence. JDOQL does that

Comment: Okay, I just ask using the simplest example. I need to join a couple of tables, and create an entity graph (with 1 to 1, and 1 to m relations) . How can I do it with JDOQL?

Comment: I already explained and pointed you to docs on FetchPlans on a different question. Somebody has already answered this below also

Answer (score 1):

JDOQL does not have "entity graph". Perhaps you mean "fetch plans", which is more flexible. Anyway, the query would be something like

```
SELECT FROM mydomain.Account WHERE :vals.contains(this.id)
```

and then define an input parameters "vals" as a List of ints. i.e Java syntax.
And set your fetch plan to load the `loanApplication` field, so add such as the following to the mapping for `Account`.

```
<fetch-group name="loanApps">
    <field name="loanApplication"/>
</fetch-group>
```

and then call

```
q.getFetchPlan().addGroup("loanApps");
```

before executing the query.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this. But after the query is executed it loads a list of Account, but its loanApplication is null. It still use lazy loading for that field, even when I'm configuring fetch group, and add it to the fetch plan. The problem is that I use DataNucleus 2, but it has the same examples with fetch groups in the docs, of second version

Comment: So use a recent version!